# Failed to connect to Redis (using redis-plus-plus)

Tags: c++, redis

So I installed Redis in OpenSuse 15.0 and everything was working well. I was using redis-cli for checking the communication with redis server and it was ok.
I wanted to use redis-plus-plus as I'm coding in C++. Installation was succesfully as it passed all tests.
But then I created my own script (inside general redis-plus-plus folder) with the following code:

```
#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace sw::redis;

int main()
{
        // Create an Redis object, which is movable but NOT copyable.
        auto redis = Redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");
        redis.set("key", "val");
}
```

It's a very simple code, just to check that connection was succesfully.

And I was compiling it as follows:

```
/usr/bin/g++-10 -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp /home/user/redis-plus-plus/test/libredis++.a /home/user/hiredis/build/libhiredis_static.a -pthread
```

Compilation was ok, but when I execute the ./main I'm getting the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sw::redis::Error'
  what():  unknown error code: Failed to connect to Redis: 
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

And I have another window with the server running, so I don't know why I can't connect with Redis server and I don't know what else can I try... The problem is with the line

> redis.set("key", "val");

because if I remove this line I have no error. Any help will be deeply apreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**: The problem above was solved, now I'm facing something similar. I'm trying to implement two more lines:

```
#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sw::redis;

int main()
{
        auto redis = Redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");
        redis.set("key", "new_val270622");
        
     
        auto redis_cluster = RedisCluster("tcp://127.0.0.1:16379"); 
        redis_cluster.set("key", "new_val");
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down
```

If I do

> ss -tulpn

I get the following ports:

[image]

In redis.config I have made the following changes:

cluster-enabled yes

cluster-config-file nodes-16379.conf

cluster-require-full-coverage yes

And I also used:

> redis-cli --cluster fix 127.0.0.1:6379

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @for_stack if you can take a look please :) many many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. First of all, use redis-cli to connect to Redis server, and check if it is able to connect to Redis. If redis-cli failed, you should check the configuration of Redis. 2. "unknown error code" means hiredis returns some error redis-plus-plus cannot handle. That's should not happen. Please check if your system has multiple hiredis installed. In that case, remove extra ones, and only install ONE hiredis. Normally, that's the root cause.

Comment: It seems that your build command for your application has no `-I` option to specify the location of hiredis header files, while it still successfully pass the building process. I doubt that your system already installed hiredis in some system folder. Please ensure there's one and only one hiredis, and redis-plus-plus installed in your system. Otherwise, you might get some wired problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @for_stack !!! I fixed the error thanks to your advices, now I updated the question because I'm getting another error... It's in UPDATE part. Maybe you know why this happens... thanks a lot

Comment: *CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down* means the cluster doesn't work correctly. You should check if your cluster has covered all slots. Google the meaning of *cluster-require-full-coverage* for detail.